# Best way to work with large json files / large data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a flutter app that has a lot of data, that I currently have in several json files on my assets. On the startup of the app I am reading some of these files but the process of reading the files takes some seconds (5-10s). This is only the time to read the file `rootBundle.loadString(path);`.

To try to improve that and reduce the time to start the app I added all this information as a static list of objects, and that solve the issue. But the problem now is that my app takes a huge amount of time to build.

Some of these json file had more than 1MB and these static lists can have up to 15k items.

Is there a way to read these json faster or to make my build faster with these huge lists?

Comment: If you're bundling the files in with the Flutter bundled assets, no, that's pretty much the only way to read it. I would suggest, though, that if you have that much static data, you shouldn't be bundling it with the app, but instead downloading it from a backend service when the app starts up for the first time. This will reduce the app's installation size and download time. Once you do that, you can use `dart:io` methods to stream the data in. That said, if the data is in JSON format, you need to load the full file in before you can use it anyway, so that won't help the speed problem.

Comment: Another approach I've done myself is to inline your JSON data inside your Dart code. I have a static dictionnary made of 500k+ words taking 6MB and that loads very fast (< 2 seconds). I tried the load asset approach but that was definitely slower.